# Python 2.7 - Cannot Import GPIOZERO

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

I am very new to RaspberryPi, Debian and Python.

I have configured my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 to the all the recommendations available from the many many helpfull websites and people. However, when I want to start a basic project based using GPIOZERO to control some buttons and LED's I am not able to use the: "from gpiozero import LED, Button" command. the output reports the following:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/init.py", line 57, in 
> from .devices import (
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 38, in 
> from .pins.rpigpio import RPiGPIOPin
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 27, in 
> class RPiGPIOPin(Pin):
>  
> ***File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 55, > in RPiGPIOPin 'i2c': GPIO.I2C,
>  
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'I2C'***
```

Can someone please shed some light on this and let me know how to get out of this situation?

Thanks very much

Comment: how did you install gpiozero? I did it with pip using `pip install gpiozero` and mine worked. I did it on win10, python 2.7

Comment: I used the following: "sudo apt-get install python3-gpiozero python-gpiozero" command and it installs with no error.

Comment: I used the "sudo apt-get install python3-gpiozero python-gpiozero" command and it installed clean with no error displayed.

Comment: try the command I used. To get pip use `sudo apt-get -y install python-pip` and let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: also you shouldn't have installed the one for python3 since you said you are working with 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all of you for your suggestions and assistance - the error was that I was loading Python with the command "python" instead of "python3". Once I ran "python3" it all worked.